# Access one domain class file in another domain using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, methods

I am working on 2 websites. Class file methods are 80% same on both domains and there is only one database for both websites. It is headache for me to add/modify any method or function in both domain's class files.
So, is there any way by which I upload files on one domain and access those all files in another domain.

Answer (score 3):

Create a separate "class library" project that both of your websites reference.

Comment: But I will need to copy that class library on both domains. Right ?

Comment: Yep. But if you use project references in Visual Studio, that will happen automatically.